# Building against 10.8 SDK and CFNetwork.framework, but app crashes in OS X 10.6.8

Tags: xcode, cocoa, frameworks

**Note:** The question is NOT a duplicate! Please read first few comments!

I have written my code on OSX 10.8 with the latest Xcode, and linked against the standalone, root-level `CFNetwork.framework` framework (`/MacOSX10.8.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework`). While the app runs fine in 10.8, it crashes on OS X 10.6.8.

It appears to me (may be wrong) that `CFNetwork.framework` doesn't exist on OSX 10.6.8.

I can only find it in the IOS programming environment but not in the OSX programming environment. Could this be because of the CFNetwork.framework not being there on OSX 10.6.8? if so, what is the correct procedure to add the framework to the project so it doesn't appear as missing on 10.6.8?

Comment: Actually read the answer in that question.  I chose it very specifically.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of that one. That question concerns a developer who, when developing in a previous version of OS X that didn't have `CFNetwork.framework` as a standalone, root-level framework, had no idea where to find it in Xcode, let alone link his app with it. This question, on the other hand, is about a developer who, in OS X 10.8, **has already linked his app against `CFNetwork.framework`, but whose application is crashing in 10.6.8** . **He has already linked his app against `CFNetwork.framework`**.

Comment: Thabks nsgod! Beeing a noob i wasnt sure if i was understanding it correctly!

Answer (score 1):

You can develop your app using the 10.8 SDK, and link against the root-level `CFNetwork.framework`, but you need to make sure you set a deployment target of 10.6. That will assure that the linker doesn't generate a strong reference to the `CFNetwork.framework`.

Compare the output of `otool` with 10.8 deployment:

```
MacPro:~ mdouma46$ otool -L /Users/mdouma46/.../CFNetwork\ Finagler 
/Users/mdouma46/.../CFNetwork\ Finagler:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
```

And 10.6 deployment target:

```
MacPro:~ mdouma46$ otool -L /Users/mdouma46/.../CFNetwork\ Finagler 
/Users/mdouma46/.../CFNetwork\ Finagler:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
```

Comment: Thanks! Will test tomorrow asap! Is there a way i might contact you privately? You seem to be the correct person to help me on a thing.. Thanks!

Comment: ehm, how am i supposed to use otool? i tried to execute it on the .app file but it doesnt work. what file do i have to run it against?